# How to get an overview of created structs in a mapping for a specific address in solidity?

Tags: struct, mapping, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

After I created some structs which belong to specific addresses I want to get an overview of structs with associated parameters regarding an address. 
So what could I do for solving this problem?

If I am running my code inside remix, I get back only my first stored struct for an address. But I want to get back all stored structs for one address. I know that we can not iterate through a mapping, but maybe it is possible to make some index-counter for the array of structs to solve it? - So is it also possible to store the index of array in a variable?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Prescribe {

struct Prescription {
        address patients_address;
        string medicament;
        string dosage_form;
        uint amount;
        uint date;
        //uint index_counter;
 }

mapping (address => Prescription[]) public ownerOfPrescription;
address [] public patients;

function createPrescription(address patients_address, string 
medicament, string dosage_form, uint amount, uint date) public  
restricted {

ownerOfPrescription[patients_address].push(Prescription({
     patients_address: patients_address,
     medicament: medicament,
     dosage_form: dosage_form,
     amount: amount,
     date: date
}));
patients.push(patients_address);
}

function getOverview(address patient) public view restricted 
returns(string, string, uint, uint) {

for(uint i = 0; i < ownerOfPrescription[patient].length; i++) {
 if(ownerOfPrescription[patient][i].patients_address == patient) {
   return(ownerOfPrescription[patient][i].medicament, 
          ownerOfPrescription[patient][i].dosage_form, 
          ownerOfPrescription[patient][i].amount, 
          ownerOfPrescription[patient][i].date);
    }
  }

}
```

So I want to have the return-values of all separate structs of one address as in the function getOverview on the screen, but it gives me back only the first struct of an address

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's returning only the first one, because after the  statement

```
 if(ownerOfPrescription[patient][i].patients_address == patient)
```

return true, your code is executing the return statement which will make the control to exit from the function, and no further statement will be executed.

Comment: Yea that makes sense, but how can I solve this problem? - maybe storing the values  in another array of structs and return them back in a second loop?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a research I made the conclusion that it is still not possible to get an array of structs as a return value. One has only the possibility to access individual elements of the array right? - If there are any updates on this topic, I would be very grateful for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to return array of struct but it will cost a little bit more gas fees.
Below is an example

```
contract Test {
struct FlexiblePlan {
    string token;
    address _address;
}
struct Plans {
    FlexiblePlan[] flexiblePlans;
}
Plans plans;
function createPlan(string memory _token, address _address) external {
    plans.flexiblePlans.push(FlexiblePlan(_token, _address));
}
function getAllPlans() external view returns(Plans memory){
    return plans;
}
```

}